# Smooth Shrinkwrap Modification

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap

I was wondering if there is a way to smooth out the results of a shrinkwrap modification.
The issue with using shrinkwrap in some cases is that detailed areas create artifacts you don't want. For instance, one vertex fitting to one face while the neighbouring vertex is fitted to a completely different face because that's the nearest surface. So that often leads to jaggy surfaces. Instead' Id rather have none of these vertices move or have both move in a similar direction. I.e. I want to smooth out the "delta" of shrinkwrap.

So, the result of a shrinkwrap ("nearest surface point") could be interpreted as an offset between the original vertex position and the new vertex position. What I want to do is apply smoothing to that offset mesh. Neighboring vertices of the original mesh should generally move in the same direction. I specifically don't want to smooth out the original mesh. I only want to smooth out the offset that the shrinkmap adds to each vertex. So simply adding a smoothing modification after the shrinkwrap won't help.

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Have you tried adding a smooth modifier to the object that you've applied the shrinkwrap to?

Comment: Yeah that's the option I mentioned doesn't do what I'm aiming for. 
When I add a smoothing modifier to the object, it will basically smooth the combination of base mesh and shrinkwrap modifier. What I want to smooth is the offset that the shrinkwrap produces. I.e., I have the original vertex position, I have the offset the shrink modifier adds on top. When I add a smothing modifier, I either smooth both base position + offset or only the base position. I want to smooth only the offset.

Comment: It might be more work than you want, but you can apply shrinkwrap based on vertex groups. That gives you the flexibility to either not apply the shrinkwrap to some parts of the mesh, or use a completely different shrink target for them.

Comment: @DaleCieslak yeah I know I can filter the shrinkwrap with vertex groups but that also doesn't give the the desired result and as you already mentioned, it's quite a bit of work. Basically at this point what I would do I's do the modification manually.